# Ember Data: Using "links" on JSON payload for hasMany relationships

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data, asp.net-web-api, has-many

Given two models in an app using **DS.RESTAdapter**:

```
App.Calendar = DS.Model.extend({
  reservations: DS.hasMany("reservation", { async: true })
});

App.Reservation = DS.Model.extend({
  date: DS.attr("date"),
  calendar: DS.belongsTo("calendar")
});
```

And payloads such as:

**/api/calendar/1:**

```
{
  "calendar": {
     "id": 1,
     "reservations": [],
     "links": {
        "reservations": "/api/calendar/1/reservations"
     }
  }
}
```

**/api/calendar/1/reservations:**

```
{
  "reservations": [
     {
        "id": 1,
        "date": "10/01/2014"
     }
  ]
}
```

Why is it that the **reservations** array on the **Calendar** model isn't being lazy-loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your json shouldn't have reservations defined twice

```
{
  "calendar": {
     "id": 1,
     "links": {
        "reservations": "/api/calendar/1/reservations"
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Even so, how come Ember doesn't even execute the HTTP request to the link?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your question, it's only called when you attempt to use the property( a la lazy loading).  Are you using the property?  I thought you were saying the model was being called immediately.

Comment: Yes, I'm using it with model.get("reservations") and saving it to a 'content' property so another controller can use it.

Comment: Solved, content was accessible through 'firstObject'.